# VS Code Intellisense can't find CMake build directory

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, cmake, intellisense

I have a VS Code CMake project which uses "Kits" to define the CMake builds:

```
[
    {
      "name": "Kit name (e.g. cross-compile)",
      "cmakeSettings": {
          ... some settings
      }
    }
]
```

In `settings.json` the kit is then used to define separate build dirs (e.g. so I can keep cross-compiled builds separate):

```
{
    ...
    "cmake.buildDirectory": "${workspaceFolder}/build-${buildKit}",
    ...
}
```

However, IntelliSense does not understand this in `c_cpp_properties.json`:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Foo",
            ...
            "compileCommands": "${workspaceFolder}/build-${command:cmake.buildKit}/compile_commands.json",
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

nor does it understand back in `settings.json`:

```
{
    "C_Cpp.default.compileCommands": "${workspaceFolder}/build-${buildKit}/compile_commands.json"
}
```

produces

```
"${workspaceFolder}/build-${buildKit}/compile_commands.json" could not be found. 'includePath' from c_cpp_properties.json in folder 'project' will be used instead.
```

even though both `${workspaceFolder}` and `${buildKit}` work in the same file for `cmake.buildDirectory`.

If I manually hardcode the location, IntelliSense works. If I do nothing (or one of the above), it can't find any include files.

What is the right way to point IntelliSense's `compileCommand` setting to the right CMake build directory?

Comment: It you're using the cmake plugin it should configure intellisense for you, just delete the `c_cpp_properties.json` file

Comment: @AlanBirtles that is why I'm trying this: the IntelliSense doesn't seem to work (tons of include errors and then it gives up) unless I manually set the `compileCommands` setting.